# Tiff Jpeg image viewer control - free / opensource

Tags: .net, jpeg, tiff, libtiff, image-compression

I have like zillions of tiff files with jpeg compression.
I am working with this library called Lib.tif .net version
it is very great and it can read/tag/save tiff with JPEG compression (6/7).
i have also tried imageMagic and FreeImage libraries (both are similar)

**problem 1 is that .NET (2.0/3.5/4.0) does not support viewing Tiff with Jpeg compression in its image viewer controls.
Does any one have a work-around? or is there any Tiff Jpeg image viewer control - free / opensource?**
*can we strip parts of tiff as bitmap and stream it to image viewer control? if so, can you please guide me?
i know there are plenty of paid versions like GDpicture or viscom or leedtools etc
but i need to have one for free.*

**problem 2** is that files open in windows 7 MODI and photo viewer and paint.net and other applications. (both 32bit and 64bit versions). BUT the same images do not open in Windows XP Fax viewer . i tried with office 2007 MODI also, but no success.
Any ideas or workarounds?

Please help.

Thanks ;
Regards
prad

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to extract the pages in a compression that can be displayed.

You may have a problem if the comression that is used is "old jpeg", in which case you need to use libtiff or something similar to convert the image.

```
public static Image[] GetFrames(Image sourceImage)
{
    Guid objGuid = sourceImage.FrameDimensionsList[0];
    FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);
    int frameCount = sourceImage.GetFrameCount(objDimension);
    Image[] images = new Image[frameCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        sourceImage.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, i);
        sourceImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        images[i] = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    return images;
}
```

Your second problem is caused by the different versions of GDI+ in Windows. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to update previous versions. You may have to use an external viewer or a different compression.